# Unable to connect to .NET 4.0 WCF web service within Flash Builder Burrito

Tags: flash, wcf, builder

I'm trying to connect to a very simple .NET WCF web service (created in .NET 4.0) within Flash Builder Burrito and the process hangs on "Introspecting the service".  I get no errors -- it just hangs.  The web service is on my local network, although not on my local machine.  Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

FB finds something wrong in service metadata and trying to check with www.w3.org 
You need to block it from that either by disconnecting from network (disable adapter or take out network plug).
Or in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc .... find hosts. text file (without extension) and add an entry at the bottom:
0.0.0.0  www.w3.org 
make sure to have new line at end.